# Does http header include zero at the end?

Tags: http, http-headers

Let's say this is the http header:

```
Content-length: 67728\r\n
Content-type: application/x-genericbytedata-octet-stream\r\n
\r\n
```

Does it include \0 at the end of the header or the "Content-length" bytes start directly after the last \n ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no null byte at the end, so no, it's not included.

Answer (score 1):

In complement.

The Body will start after the end of the headers. And of the headers is "\r\n\r\n",  <strike>"\n\r\n",  "\r\n\n" or "\n\n"</strike> (that is two valid end-of-line sequences).

Adding an "\0" somewhere in your headers will almost certainly makes the server reject your request (silently or not). Trying to inject NULL character in a request is usually considered as an attack attempt.

In HTTP line separator syntax is "\r\n", and usually this is what the parsers are seeking, not the NULL character. With one optional exception, in headers, where a line starting with a space may be considered as part of the previous header (this is the obs-fold syntax), so "X:B\r\n Z\r\n" is in fact the header "X" with value "B Z".

Comment: [The only specified line-ending in HTTP is CRLF (`\r\n`)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3).

Comment: Well, I think you're right. I'll fix that, I tend to mix my mind between implmentations and the RFC :-)

Comment: @Codecaster I also found this in the RFC: `Although the line terminator for the start-line and header fields is the sequence CRLF, a recipient MAY recognize a single LF as a line terminator and ignore any preceding CR`...

Comment: Yeah, MAY, because there are buggy old clients and servers and the "robustness" principle, which is flawed. Just stay close to the specs.

Comment: It also helps people testing HTTP via telnet, where enter usually means only `\n`